# HP 2920 - Can stack without stacking module?

Tags: switch, hp-procurve, stacking

Is it possible to stack HP 2920 switches via ethernet connections (without add-in stacking modules)? I've consulted several of the docs on HPs site but can't find a definitive answer. I have older switches that are stacked this way.

Comment: Can we see the configs from the older HP switches you say are stacked via ethernet? Can you run the HP equivalent of "show switch" on the older switch stack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I attempted to stack the switches referencing the guides provided, but the commands were invalid, seemingly not applying to this device. I upgraded to the latest firmware to be sure it wasn't from having an old version. No luck.

I contacted HP support which told me this:

> The stacking on this switch is different than the other procurve switches. There needs to be a stacking module attached to the switch to enable stacking.

So it appears that **a stacking module is required to stack the 2920**. Thanks for all the help. I'm going to buy stack modules now. I'm not sure how this will interact with other procurve switches in a stack. I wish the guides were more clear about all this up-front but maybe this posting will help others.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes.

The long answer is search the HP site for the 2920 series switches, support documents, setup and install documents, and download the Advanced Traffic Management Guide.  You will want to pay attention to Chapter 6.  Chapter 7 deals with the stacking modules.

Here is a [link to the doc](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c03673784-2%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)

Answer (score 1):

Yes but its only going to be for management via a single IP.  If you want the actual backplane stacking for performance and redundancy, you are going to need the modules.  The 2920s and 3800s are the only switches in the ProCurve line that can do this, and it is similar to IRF on the Comware line.